# Adding options to mobile gallery?

Tags: android, gridview, gallery

Can we add any other extra options like set wallpaper or add any extra button to action bar for mobile gallery programmatically in android. In my application i have a grid View with num of images taken from mobile gallery.

When grid view item click it directly navigate to image location which is mobile gallery. I have done this using concept MediaScannerConnection.

Now I want to add extra option to mobile built in gallery.

Is there any possible ways to do this?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image to set wallpaper. Similarly the image can be used as "set contact pic" or "set as app icon", then you will select the app you want to change its icon. change icon of any app and use ur own icon search this in google u have to write code for this..but this is hard...